# HTML относительный путь — не могу разобраться — почему после добавления слэша в URL в конце путь меняется?

Tags: html

Адресная строка браузера: `http://mysite/literature`

href ссылки: `href="literature/guidebooks"`

Навожу на ссылку и внизу слева в хроме показывается ее url: `http://mysite/literature/guidebooks`

Добавляю в адресную строку слэш:

Адресная строка: `http://mysite/literature/`

href ссылки: `href="literature/guidebooks"`

Навожу на ссылку и внизу слева в хроме показывается ее url:
`http://mysite/literature/literature/guidebooks`

Почему так происходит? Почему добавляется еще один `literature/`?

Comment: Правильно использовать абсолютные пути, добавлять `/` в начале ссылки, например `/literature/`, тогда ссылка будет на `http://mysite/literature/` абсолютно из любого пути внутри сайта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `http://mysite/literature` загрузить **файл** `literature` из корня сайта
- `http://mysite/literature/` загрузить индексный файл из **папки** `literature`, которая находится в корне сайта
- `href="literature/guidebooks"` загрузить **файл** `guidebooks`, который лежит в папке `literature` в текущей папке

Соответственно в первом случае - текущая папка это корень сайта, а во втором - папка `literature`

То, что Ваш сервер интерпретирует запрос к файлу и к индексному файлу в папке как один запрос, браузера не касается и не интересует